# Can a New Zealander get a multi entry visa for Zimbabwe on arival?

Tags: visas, multiple-entry, new-zealand-citizens, zimbabwe

I will be landing in Victoria Falls and starting a truck tour which goes through Zambia and back into Zimbabwe. When I called the Zimbabwe embassy in London, they said that I will need to get two single entry visas at the border ($50 each). They didn't want to give me any info on multiple entry visas. Is it possible to get one at the port of entry?

Comment: Apparently there is also a "double entry visa". And one tour site says multi entry are not given at port of entry, but only in the town office. Not sure on either of these.

Comment: I've been doing a lot of reading on this recently and it looks like pot luck. Two singles are only marginally more expensive than the double anyway, it was only really for the convenience of a quicker second entry. I'll post how I get on in October when I get back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I landed at Vic Falls the options I was given is $30USD for single entry or $45USD for double entry. The prices were the same for the Americans, Swiss and Germans I spoke to in the queue.

A point to note, there was one immigration officer charging people for a double entry and placing a single entry visa in there passport and writing them a receipt for a double so it pays to check the visa as its going in.

Answer (score 7):

According to the Zimbabwe Embassy in the US, NZ can get a multi-entry visa on arrival.

Find New Zealand on the list [here](http://zimbabwe-embassy.us/subpage6.html).

You can find the prices [here](http://www.zimbabwe-embassy.us/subpage1.html). Currently it says 95USD for a multi-entry visa.

Comment: If I was crossing three times that would be good value as a single entry is 50USD but hopefully it should make the second crossing nice and speedy.